# Facebook current UID with FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

How can i get my current UID with FQL.. i want to save traffic and requests with getting the the friends of a user with fql.multiquery

"query1": GET NEED MY USERID
"query2":"SELECT uid, first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE  uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=MYUSERID) order by first_name"

should return my friends! getting users with friends.get and then users.getInfo needs 2 requests and is not optimal...

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first query should be entirely unnecessary, as Facebook always provides the `uid` to an application via the `fb_sig_user` parameter (POST or GET).  I'm not sure what kind of FQL query you could use to get a `uid` based on some other form of information.  There's no `sessions` table or anything available to FQL (available tables are listed [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FQL_Tables)).

For multi-queries however, I'm fairly certain that [this page](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fql.multiquery) describes exactly what you need to do, but I'll throw some code together in the way that I would do it.

If it was a PHP app, and I wanted to do this server side, I would create a couple of JSON-formatted strings and send them as a query as follows:

```
$fql= '{
 "userinfo":"SELECT uid FROM user_standard_info WHERE first_name=\'zombat\'",
 "friends":"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 IN (SELECT uid FROM #userinfo)}"
}';
$res = $facebook->api_client->fql_multiquery($fql);

print_r($res['userinfo']);
print_r($res['friends']);
```

This should produce a dump of your query results.

Assuming you have your current `uid` available from the `fb_sig_user` parameter (which you should), then your problem should be solved by something like this:

```
$fql= '{
 "friends":"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1='.$your_uid.',"
 "friendinfo":"SELECT * FROM standard_user_info WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #friends)"
}';
$res = $facebook->api_client->fql_multiquery($fql);
```

**Note**:  You may want to have a careful look at some of the queries you're trying to do.  Many tables, such as `friend`, can only be used if you're dealing with a logged-in user.

Answer (score 1):

The function `me()` returns your user id in FQL.

To get the list of your friends, you can use:

```
SELECT uid, first_name, last_name
FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

You can find the documentation of this here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/